Add Signature while replying using Selection c# vsto addin
I am new to C# VSTO Add-In development and am trying to add a signature at the cursor's location. However, I'm unable to insert HTML and can only add plain text. How can I append HTML instead?
I tried the code below and was able to add text. How can I append HTML instead?
// Get the active Inspector (email editor)
Outlook.Inspector inspector = outlookApp.ActiveInspector();

if (inspector != null && inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
    // Get the Word editor for the email
    Document wordDocument = inspector.WordEditor as Document;

    if (wordDocument != null)
    {
        // Access the current selection (cursor position)
        Selection selection = wordDocument.Application.Selection;

        if (selection != null)
        {
            // Insert HTML at the current selection (cursor position)
            Range range = selection.Range;
            selection.TypeText(signature);
            // Set the range's HTML format to preserve HTML tags
            range.FormattedText = wordDocument.Application.Selection.FormattedText;
            // Set the email's HTML body to include the new HTML content
            //mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody.Insert(mailItem.HTMLBody.Length, "Ram");
            return "NOTREQUIRED";
        }

    }
}

Then tried below code,
//Insert the HTML content at the current cursor position
 selection.Range.InsertAfter(htmlContent);

HTML is not being added in this location. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Can you help me figure it out?


Used tricky way, just paste the HTML using below functions, and it's working.
public void SetClipboardHtml(string htmlContent)
{
    string preamble = "Version:0.9\r\n";
    string htmlStart = "<html><body><!--StartFragment-->";
    string htmlEnd = "<!--EndFragment--></body></html>";

    string fullHtml = htmlStart + htmlContent + htmlEnd;

    int startHtml = preamble.Length;
    int startFragment = startHtml + htmlStart.Length;
    int endFragment = startFragment + htmlContent.Length;
    int endHtml = endFragment + htmlEnd.Length;

    string clipboardFormat = $"{preamble}" +
        $"StartHTML:{startHtml:D8}\r\n" +
        $"EndHTML:{endHtml:D8}\r\n" +
        $"StartFragment:{startFragment:D8}\r\n" +
        $"EndFragment:{endFragment:D8}\r\n" +
        $"{fullHtml}";
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetText(clipboardFormat, TextDataFormat.Html);
}

if (selection != null)
{
    SetClipboardHtml(signature);
    selection.Paste();
    return "NOTREQUIRED";
}


Try to use Range.InsertFile to insert the signature's HTML file.

This is being added as an attachment instead of appending to the existing HTML content.

When you call Range.InsertFile? Or are you are using Attachments.Add?

I need to add the signature design as rich text instead of adding it as plain text. Updated the question, Please have a look.

TypeText assumes plain text. Once again, do use Range.InsertFile - it figures out the text type (txt/html/rtf) based on the file extension.

It's adding as attachment.

Dopes the file have the right extension?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'd rather keep in the discussion open for the benefit of others.

// Insert HTML at the current selection (cursor position)
Range range = selection.Range;
// Load HTML into HtmlAgilityPack document
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(signature);
// Create a temporary file to save the HTML content
string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "temp.html");
File.WriteAllText(tempFilePath, signature);
range.InsertFile(tempFilePath);
// Optionally delete the temp file
File.Delete(tempFilePath);

In Word: The InsertFile method appends the content of the file at the specified range in the document.
In Outlook: The same method adds the file as an attachment to the email.

Is there anything wrong here? I await your response.

If you are already using HtmlAgilityPack, you can easily merge the current HTML document (MailItem.HTMLBody) and the signature, and then set the resulting HTML back. You'd also need to handle image attachments (must be added explicitly) and styles.

Yes, I’ve already tried that. However, identifying the exact selection range in the HTML editor is challenging. It’s straightforward for a new email, but in cases of replies or partially composed emails, tracking the selection becomes more complex.

So essentially you are trying to do is what Insert | Signature in Outlook does?

Yes, at the cursor's position (within the selection range).
